# Loop through an array of objects and get where object.field equals value

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, loops

I'm currently working on a small application where I have to loop through an enormous array of objects. What would be the most efficient method to perform this?

```
var array = [
  {
    id: "1",
    name: "Alpha"
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    name: "Beta"
  },
  ...
];
```

I'd like to get each object where `name` equals `"Alpha"`. I'm currently using a simple `if` statement to filter the objects with a different `name` value out, but I wonder if there's a more efficient way to do this, performance-wise.

It's worth to mention that I'll push the matching results into a new array.

Comment: Show what are you doing You could user `filter` or `map` depending what you really want to do,

Comment: @Tomalak enormous as in potentially more than ten thousand objects. There's nothing wrong with my current code, I'm simply asking if there are more efficient ways to filter out the required objects.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no more efficient way.

The alternative is to build and maintain some kind of internal data structure which allows you to find the desired elements faster. As usual, the trade off is between the work involved in maintaining such a structure vs the time it saves you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any way about which I would know it's more effective.

But if you had your objects ordered by name you could stop your search imideatly upon reaching an object whose name is not equal to "Alpha".

To find the first object you're looking for you can use binary search and from this  Object you go up and down until at both ends you reach an object which isn't named "Alpha" or the end of array.

This is only a way of optimizing and will require time to sort the array and also will take more time when adding an element.

Answer (score 0):

There's a JavaScript function exactly for this kind of task. **Filter**

**From the Docs**

> The filter() method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.

Here is a small example by code for getting all element from array which has a certain 'name' field:

```js
const arr = [
  {name: 'Abc'},
  {name: 'Xyz'},
  {name: 'Lmn'},
  {name: 'Xyz'},
  {name: 'Xyz'}
];

let response = findByName('Xyz');
console.log(response);

function findByName (name) {
  return arr.filter((element) => {
    return element.name = name;
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need more than one time a collection with a given name, you could use an object with the names as hashes and have instantly access to the items.

```js
var array = [{ id: "1", name: "Alpha" }, { id: "2", name: "Beta" }, { id: "3", name: "Beta" }, { id: "4", name: "Gamma" }, { id: "5", name: "Beta" }, { id: "2", name: "Alpha" }],
    hash = Object.create(null);
    
array.forEach(function (a) {
    if (!hash[a.name]) {
        hash[a.name] = [];
    }
    hash[a.name].push(a);
});

console.log(hash);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: @Kinduser, it's a different approach by grouping all names to own arrays. the speed comes later with fast access by using the name as key for the object.